# resultSet next() method not returning any value

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

not getting what is wrong with this code. but when i run query separately i am getting single column output. but ResultSet next() method is returning no value. Please help. anyway i am getting null value always.

```
package magicNumberGame;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class GetQuery {

    GetMagicNumber getMagicNumber = new GetMagicNumber();   
    String SelectQuery;
    String  query;

    public void selectQuery()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl","SYSTEM","Rajak1991@");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        SelectQuery = "SELECT QUERY FROM MAIN_QUIZ_QUERY WHERE SERIAL_NO=15";

        ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(SelectQuery);    

        while(result.next())
        {
            query = result.getString(1);
            con.close();
        }

    }catch(SQLException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
 }  

    public String getQuery()
    {
        return query;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GetQuery g = new GetQuery();
        g.selectQuery();
        System.out.println("main method : "+ g.getQuery());//  
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried System.out.println(query); after result.getString(1);

Comment: Does your code enter the `while` loop or just skip over it?

Comment: Please edit your question and include an example of the data in your table, the output produced by your program, and the output you expect your program to produce. Also, tell us what happens when you step through your code in a debugger. Thanks.

Comment: I assume you mean that `ResultSet.next()` is returning false, as it most definitely always returns a value (either true or false).

Comment: my code is not entering in the while loop. simply skipping it.

Comment: If it's skipping the while() your next() returns false - so the query just does not find any rows to return. Please close resultset, statement and connection even in this case (use try-with-resource)